# How can I destroy and redraw a view without refreshing the entire page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, view

I am using backbone.js to create a page. My code contains many models and views. I wonder if it is possible to destroy a view and then redraw it without refreshing the page, and if so, what is the best way to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myHomeCollectionView = new MyHomeCollectionView({});
});

var MyHomeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyHome
});

var MyHomeCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#home",
    initialize: function(options){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');

        this.collection = new MyHomeCollection();

        /-- Rest initialize the code --/
    },

    render: function(){
        /-- Render code --/
    }
})
```

this is a sample code of my view..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is certainly possible. The main benefit of a JS framework is being able to change the content of the page without refreshing it.

I am not sure why you want to destroy the view, that is usually not necessary.

If you simply want to re-render the same view, you usually just listen for an event then call render. Take a look at the example below of re-rendering your view based on when the collection reloaded.

```
var MyHomeCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#home",
  initialize: function(options){
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');

    this.collection = new MyHomeCollection();

    // re-render view when collection is reloaded
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset sync', this.render);

    /-- Rest initialize the code --/
  },

  render: function(){
    /-- Render code --/
  }
})
```

Or you can replace a view with another view. You can do this by simply rendering another view into the same element. Check out this jsfiddle for a very simple example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/1g1j7afa/2/.

If you want to get more advanced, you can check out Marionette LayoutView. It is a nice way to handle the adding/replacing of sub views.

Comment: Good point. Updated fiddle to remove previous view. This is good reason to use Marionette as it does that all for you.